# Request JSON in a background process in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am new to iOS development. I am working on an app that loads some of its settings when the app is loading. It used to request JSON from an external url.

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) 
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.domain.com/jsonkeys.php"] 

#import "SyncJsonSettings.h"

@implementation SyncJsonSettings

(void)sync{

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSError* error;
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:kLatestKivaLoansURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:str waitUntilDone:YES];

    });    
}
```

If the Internet is not available, the whole app freezes. I think this because of the main thread. Can someone help me to do this in a background thread?

Comment: before calling for JSON check internet Connectivity.

Comment: If network connection is ok, but network is too slow this request process get more time.

Comment: Please don't use `k` to name macros that evaluate to function calls or message sends. `k` means "constant".

Comment: In this code nothing wrong. Try to debug you app, I think you miss something in code. And I recomend use AFNetworking for HTTP request, it's really powerfull framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, just change this  `waitUntilDone:YES` with `waitUntilDone:NO`

after that do 2 things
Implement one of the following

1) [Apple's reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

2) [Tony Millio's Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

and check network status then host status(So that you can display proper message etc) and then call the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to connect the app to a website like:

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; // or your website
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];

if (data) {
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
    // YOUR CODE
} else {

          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Can't connect to the internet..."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

          [alert show];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used  Apple's version of Reachability.h and Reachability.m to the project for checking the network status.

```
-(void)sync{

if (![self isConnected]) {
    // not connected
} else {
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSError* error;
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:kLatestKivaLoansURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:str waitUntilDone:YES];

    });

}
```

}
   - (BOOL)isConnected{

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```